# Can I use bluez to read extended advertising data?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have a device that is sending extended advertising data. I am currently using the [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) library to read advertising data, however it does not seem to be showing the extended advertising data, only the legacy data.

I have looked into its source code and confirmed that its using the bluez MGMT api to discover devices. I can see in btmon that extended data is received through HCI events, however there doesn't seem to be any MGMT events that contain this data. **Is there another way in bluez to access this data or is parsing HCI events and reconstructing the data the only way?**

I wish to modify this library to support reading extended advertising data. What is the best way to do this using bluez?